# iOS DOM tree isn't representing the objects on screen

Tags: ios, dom, appium

I have an iOS app and i'm trying to run automated tests on it using Appium.

Some of my tests are failing because some objects are missing from the DOM tree. But when I look at the simulator screen, I see that those objects are there.

What can possibly create those differences? I'm not even sure who's fault is this - 
Is it bad iOS code in it? Is it Apple's fault? Or is it Appium's fault?

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean the driver's page source xml with "DOM". I know what DOM means but want to be sure we are thinking about the same thing.

Comment: I mean that when inspecting the application on Appium's inspector I don't see the elements under XCUIElementTypeApplication in the tree and also can't use them with the appium driver on the automation run.

Comment: I have no idea what's causing this problem, but can try help you debug it a bit.
To eliminate a Appium inspector problem, please check the [driver page source](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/) and see if you can find the element in the xml code. As you may know, appium uses this xml as a base resource for selecting elements on a gui, and possibly also to display elements in the page hierarchy shown by Appium's inspector tool.

Comment: I can't find the element in the driver page source as well. I've printed the page source and looked at the xml and didn't see the node

Comment: OK, so Appium is not able to find those object on screen and thus not displaying them in the Appium inspector tool. Do you know if the app you are testing uses custom controls (controls the dev team made, 3th party controls from a framework...)? That might be the cause, look [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8090#issuecomment-294615831).

Answer (score 1):

Taking your feedback into account, there could be several reasons why a element does not show up in Appium but clearly visible on the screen of the device/emulator you use. The ones I know off or read about:

- It's a OS problem. Appium depends on the accessibility layer from the OS. Updating or downgrading your OS *could* solve this problem, but no warranty here.
- The app is using custom controls. A custom control will only be accessible if the devs that made the controls implemented accessibility for it.
- There is also the possibility that you encountered a bug, known or unknown. Be sure to check the [Appium github issues](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues) for known bugs, or to get help from the devs tackling a new one.

If trying another version of the OS or implementing accessibility does not solve the problem or is not possible, you will need to tap your element using coordinates. This is a last resort solution if everything else fails.

A very useful article on the problems mentioned above can be found [here](https://appiumpro.com/editions/22). It also contains all the resources to address these specific problems, like how to tap by coordinates the right way.